# Can an assemble target be silenced if there are no matching files? (Without using --force)

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

I have this [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble) grunt target:

```
docs: {
  files: {'<%= site.tmp %>/': ['<%= site.pages %>/**/*.html'] }
},
```

If there is no matching content, it complains, saying "Warning: Source files not found. Use --force to continue". The task then aborts. I don't mind the warning but I would like the option to configure the task to continue rather than having to use "--force" on the command line. Is this possible?

ps. The reason why this task is now failing is that I have converted the content to markdown. I am trying to build a scaffold that allows users to use markdown, hbs or html in any combination.

Comment: create an issue on github. sounds like a good feature request.

Comment: actually is this an assemble error or a grunt error? this problem can easily be solved with other assemble solutions, but the question is about error messages. if you want other ideas perhaps you should create a new question about what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are saying, you can use a little unix trick here.

```
docs: {
  files: {'<%= site.tmp %>/': ['<%= site.pages %>/**/*.{html,hbs,md}'] }
},
```

That code basically looks for anything ending in `.html`, `.hbs`, or `.md`.

Since this is really a Grunt error, you would need to simply write your `file` object to allow for more possibilities.

For example, the above would only work if the location actually has files. If Grunt looks in that location and doesn't see any of the acceptable files, it will display the error you are getting now.