# How to have gruntjs skip eslint task if no files are found?

Tags: gruntjs, eslint, grunt-eslint

I'm using grunt with the grunt-eslint plugin. This is part of a larger grunt task that first finds changed files and does various tasks with them. If there aren't any JS files changed (for example if I just change a CSS file) the whole task aborts because eslint fails with a "could not find any files to validate" message.

```
$ grunt eslint:precommit
Running "eslint:precommit" (eslint) task
Could not find any files to validate.
Warning: Task "eslint:precommit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I don't want the task to fail if there aren't any JS files found.

Is there a way to either:

A. Have the grunt task not even call eslint and not fail if no files are run?

B. Have eslint not fail if no files are run?

(Related, but specific to a different tool called from grunt: [Can an assemble target be silenced if there are no matching files? (Without using --force)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286174/can-an-assemble-io-subtask-be-silenced-if-there-are-no-matching-files-without))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Dynamic task is your solution, here the link for the docs: http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks

Related links:

- [How can I skip a grunt task if a directory is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467905/how-can-i-skip-a-grunt-task-if-a-directory-is-empty)

Comment: Thanks. So basically there is no option to skip a task if files aren't found, but I can create my own task that checks for files and calls the task I want to call if they are found? That's fine, I'm just trying to get grunt.file.isMatch to find the files now.

Comment: And it's not grunt.file.isMatch, but grunt.file.expand that actually finds files. Blogged about it here: http://www.marcstober.com/blog/2016/01/07/grunt-file-match-and-grunt-file-ismatch-do-not-access-file-system/